# Days Countdown Timer in Ubuntu Menu Bar

Tags: notification, clock

I need an applet that can count up to specific number of days. I'm currently using the 'alarm-clock-applet' from Software Center but it can only count up to 24 hours. I need a countdown timer in Days which will be visible on top notification area along with regular clock.

Answer (score 1):

Timer applet is what I reccomend. It does have a limit of 48 hours the exact program name is Timer-applet Another one is Alarm-clock  alarm clock is less limited and it is the best choice. Also there is a widget here (http://www.toggl.com/public/widgets)

Comment: Thanks ! But, I already have that applet (alarm-clock-applet). I need a way to add a Days column in that Applet or another applet which shows Days in Notification Area.

Comment: The first one did count days I believe.

Comment: It's not supported in Unity I guess. Also, I cannot find it in Software Center.