# Countdown Timer to a specific day beside the clock in Ubuntu Menu Bar

Tags: gnome, 20.04, software-recommendation, gnome-shell-extension

I have tried searching for a countdown timer app which shall count the number of days till a specific date (for example, Christmas) so that it is visible to me all the time but, I'm not able to find any extension or app like that for Ubuntu.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Could you suggest me some apps/Gnome Extensions?

PS:

- alarm-clock-applet seems to be discontinued, and I did find an extension for Chrome, but I use Firefox, hence inefficient.
- There is a question here with the same demand, but could not be resolved: [Days Countdown Timer in Ubuntu Menu Bar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444932/days-countdown-timer-in-ubuntu-menu-bar)

Comments:

- It feels, this question might also remain unresolved as the previous one.